# can't resolve symbol ResultSet in IntelliJ

Tags: mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea, resultset

I created a project that has add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin` as a library to the project using `IntelliJ 13`, but when I tried to `import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet`, the IDE shows that it can not resolve the symbol `ResultSet`. I'm wondering how to resolve the issue.

[EDIT] when I tried `import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;`, it has no problem.

cheers

Comment: You should - almost - never have a reason to import implementations of JDBC interfaces, instead you should use the interfaces provided by `java.sql.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking inside the MySQL Connector/J .jar file (e.g., by using the Package Explorer tree view in Eclipse) we see that `com.mysql.jdbc` does contain `PreparedStatement.class` but does not contain `ResultSet.class`

[image: classes.png]

That is, you cannot

```java
import com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet
```

because it doesn't exist. What you really want to do is import `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`, etc. from `java.sql`, as in

```java
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

or the lazy option

```java
import java.sql.*;
```